# Scala StringLike split method creates extra double quotes for leading spaces

Tags: string, scala, split, space, double-quotes

I tried a simple split for a csv styled string, that contains spaces after commas like this:

```
scala> """"First", "SecondAfterSpace"""".split(",")
res0: Array[String] = Array("First", " "SecondAfterSpace"")

scala> res0(0)
res3: String = "First"

scala> res0(1)
res4: String = " "SecondAfterSpace""
```

The second string of the result Array has **unexpected double quotes**, more than the original string has.

It is ok that is contains the additional space in the beginning as I did not yet trim it. But I would expect a similar result as in the following with an additional leading space, instead of the extra double quotes:

```
scala> """"First","SecondNoSpace"""".split(",")
res1: Array[String] = Array("First", "SecondNoSpace")
```

I know I can workaround this issue with the following, but I'd like to understand if I do something wrong or if this is a bug:

```
scala> """"First", "SecondAfterSpaceTrimmed"""".split(",").map(_.trim)
res2: Array[String] = Array("First", "SecondAfterSpaceTrimmed")
```

Just to be sure I also tried all variants like

```
.split(',')
.split(""",""")
.split("""\,""")
.split(Array(','))
```

but all with the same result of extra double quotes.

In that context: From the scala-doc I see that the method in StringLike is used. The documentation talks about a char array. Yet I can use regex, which is not documented, so it made me suspicious if it is using the split method in a Java String... I am confused...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not. That is the way REPL represents it:

```
scala> val xs = """"First", "SecondAfterSpace"""".split(",")
xs: Array[String] = Array("First", " "SecondAfterSpace"")

scala> xs.last
res0: String = " "SecondAfterSpace""

scala> xs.last.count(_ == '"')
res1: Int = 2
```

As you can see, there is no extra quotes

To trim spaces after quote you may use regexp in split:

```
scala> val xs = """"First", "SecondAfterSpace"""".split(",[ ]?")
xs: Array[String] = Array("First", "SecondAfterSpace")
```

Comment: A more general regular expression for the split would be: `""",\p{Space}*"""`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the regex ignoring the space. So scala split seems to take regex despite of the scala doc which talks about separators (chars) - no mention of regex there.

Comment: @fredfred [Scala strings are Java strings](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$@String=String) and [Java strings have split method which takes regexp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). StringLike pimps Java string with split methods which accepts separator(s) as either one char or array of chars

Comment: @om-nom-nom thanks, this perfectly resolves my confusion! Simple method signatures do the routing to either implementation.